# Error with custom doctrine annnotations: [Creation Error] The annotation declared on property does not have a property named "mapping¨

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I try to link the annotation in mine class to a annotation class I keep getting following error:

```
[Creation Error] The annotation @Verzeilberg\UploadField declared on property App\Entity\UserProfile::$image does not have a property named "mapping". Available properties:
```

I have following class where I implement the annotation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Verzeilberg;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserProfileRepository")
 */
class UserProfile
{

.........................

    /**
     * @Verzeilberg\UploadField(mapping="profile_image")
     */
    protected $image;

............................
```

And this is the annotation class:

```
<?php


namespace verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Mapping\Annotation;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"PROPERTY"})
 */
class UploadField
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $mapping;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMapping(): string
    {
        return $this->mapping;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $mapping
     */
    public function setMapping(string $mapping): void
    {
        $this->mapping = $mapping;
    }
```

I did follow following Doctrine annotation example:

[Introduction Doctrine annotation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.10/index.html)

But what am I missing?

Comment: on the given documentation page, the annotation property is marked as `public` and no longer need getter/setter.

Comment: I already tried that. But keep getting the same error.

Comment: @VieStar that's weird, did you correctly empty the cache ?

Comment: The answer given bij @rugolinifr was the correct answer. I don't know why it worked suddenly but it does.